# How can I read the log stream of a DataSource using setLogWriter

Tags: java, mysql, datasource

I need to be able to watch the query log of an application using a database pool. I have found that the DataSource allows me to use setLogWriter with PrintWriter.

I have to process the information that will be output, so I don't want to send them to a file. Is it possible to read the stream of information from the datasource by converting it to a string as it being streamed?

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + db_host + ":3306/" + db_name+"?logger=StandardLogger&profileSQL=true");

        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        p.setUsername(db_user);
        p.setPassword(db_pwd);
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        //p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(maxActive);
        p.setMaxIdle(5);
        p.setInitialSize(minActive);
        p.setMaxWait(30000);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(300);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(60000);
        p.setMinIdle(3);


        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
                + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setPoolProperties(p);
        ds.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(...)); <-- Watch the output live of the PrintWriter
```

I would like to redirect setLogWriter to watch function that will allow me to reading and process the information as a String as it is being output. Example:

```
Public void analyzeLog(String fromPrintWriter){
   if(fromPrintWriter.startsWith("abc"){
       CODE HERE... ETC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [`PipedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedWriter.html)
and [`PipedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedReader.html)
you can make a `Reader` for *reading* the log output.

[image: pipe]

Applied to your case the code might look similar to this:

```
ds = new DataSource();
ds.setPoolProperties(p);
PipedWriter pipedWriter = new PipedWriter();
ds.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(pipedWriter));

Runnable runnable = () -> {
    // setup a Reader for reading the DataSource's log output
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new PipedReader(pipedWriter))) {
        // start reading from PipedReader, so that writing to PipedWriter will not block
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            analyzeLog(line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: You don't need all that.

Answer (score 0):

Just write yourself a class that extends `PrintWriter` and delegates to another one after executing your code.